# What IP-addresses do I need to allow the firewall to access geocoder.api.here.com?

Tags: ip-address, here-api, web-application-firewall

We want to use heremaps geocoder.api.
Currently the calls to heremaps are stopped by our local firewall.
Our admins told me that it is not possible to add an URL to the firewall rules (geocoder.api.here.com). They need IP-addresses.
So the question is: What IP addresses does the service "geocoder.api.here.com" use?

Thanks for your answers,
Markus

Comment: Hi,Can you try to allow this IP: 18.196.237.149 to the firewall.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This is probably only one of many IP adresses, thats behind the URL. We found out, that for 5 requests to here maps we got 5 different IP adresses.

Answer (score 0):

IP address are dynamic in nature as the APIs are hosted in a cloud environment, the recommendation is to whitelist domain like *.api.here.com or *hereapi.com in order to avoid dependency on IPs.

Comment: Please flag a comment as NLN or using custom mod flag. Don't make remarks about comments in the post.