# How can I receive a network location without Gapps or root access?

Tags: android

I have to get the location of a device, as accurately as possible. Since GPS doesn't work well in areas with lots of high buildings, I'll have to use the network location sometimes. The device doesn't come with Gapps, and I tried installing them myself, which also doesn't seem to work.

This device comes with its own special OS, so I can't flash custom ROMs or anything like that. I've tried to install MicroG as a replacement for all Gapps features, but it seems I need root access for that, which I also can't acquire.

I'd also prefer to not use a paid API, as I don't know exactly how many times this is going to be used, but it could be a lot.

Not sure if you need this, but the Android version is 4.4.4, API 19, Codename KitKat.

Does anyone know a solution to this? Please also let me know if paid API is the only solution.

Comment: My answer to a similar question: [Android Fusedlocationproviderclient not working with APN Sim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819974/295004) may be useful. As the device never had Google Services, such a non-consumer device will need a paid third-party API for urban location support.

Comment: If not gps then you are using mobile network right ? Then what is the issue with that?